# Calculate Date Difference in Power BI with multiple tables joined

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates in Power Bi. I need to join 3 separate tables in order to get the correct data back. Here is my Dax(Measure) code

```
Average Decision Time = CALCULATE(
DATEDIFF(Enquiries_venues[RecordCreated],EnquiryStatusVersion[RecordCreated], DAY),
FILTER ( Enquiries, Enquiries[TestEnquiry] = 0 && (Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 45 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 50 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 55 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 56 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 60)),
FILTER ( Enquiries_Venues, Enquiries_Venues[EnquiryVenueProposalId] = 60),
FILTER ( EnquiryStatusVersion, EnquiryStatusVersion[EnquiryStatusId] = 45)
```

)

However the date-diff part is not able to recognize the tables at this point. When I put this section at the bottom it also doesn't work as the calculate function requires the expression to come first.

Here is the error message 
[image]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing table columns into `DATEDIFF` instead of scalar dates that it expects.

Try wrapping those columns in an aggregate function like `MAX` in order to get a single date value.

Comment: I need to get the average so ideally i want the sum of all the time differences and divide that by the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following measure?

```
Average Decision Time = CALCULATE(
AVERAGE(DATEDIFF(Enquiries_venues[RecordCreated],EnquiryStatusVersion[RecordCreated], DAY)),
FILTER ( Enquiries, Enquiries[TestEnquiry] = 0 && (Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 45 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 50 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 55 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 56 || Enquiries[EnquiryStatusId] = 60)),
FILTER ( Enquiries_Venues, Enquiries_Venues[EnquiryVenueProposalId] = 60),
FILTER ( EnquiryStatusVersion, EnquiryStatusVersion[EnquiryStatusId] = 45)
```

Comment: I then get the error saying the AVERAGE function only accepts a column reference as an argument

Comment: Without the actual data, it is difficult to explain or correct. Why dont you follow the following steps. Create a Calculated Column 'Duration' and use the DATEDIFF. On the Duration column, use the AVERAGE function in the above CALCULATE formula.

Comment: By the way, could you post the relationship structure tab between different tables as an image? would like see the types of relationships